# what is little o double bar, is it like big O notation?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

[This is from my book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpzrT.jpg)

What is this little $\bar{\bar{o}}$?
My opinion is that this is the big $O$ notation.

But if it was the big O notation then why in the first line of the expansion they put $\overset{=}{o}(x^2)$ instead of $\overset{=}{o}(x^3)$, because the term that have $x^2$ is already before $\overset{=}{o}(x^2)$, right?

In case you didn't understand the image (because it's messed up) :

\begin{array}{l}
f(x)=\frac{\sqrt[n]{1+x}-1}{x}=\frac{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{x}=\frac{1+\frac{1}{n} \cdot x+\frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 \cdot\left(\frac{1}{n}-1\right) \cdot x^{2}+\overset{=}{o}\left(x^{2}\right)-1}{x} \\
=\frac{\frac{1}{n} x+\frac{1-n}{2 n^{2}} x^{2}+\overset{=}{o}\left(x^{2}\right)}{x}=\frac{x \cdot\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1-n}{2 . n^{2}} x+\overset{=}{o}(x)\right)}{x}=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1-n}{2 \cdot n^{2}} \cdot x+\overset{=}{o}(x) \\
\Rightarrow \quad \lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sqrt[n]{1+x}-1}{x}=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1-n}{2 \cdot n^{2}} \cdot x+\overset{=}{o}(x)\right)=\frac{1}{n}
\end{array}

Comment: To display $\bar{\bar{o}}$ the command is `\bar{\bar{o}}`.  You can also use `\overline{\overline{o}}` for a similar appearance, but the lines are a bit more spread out: $\overline{\overline{o}}$.  You can also use `\overset{=}{o}` to get $\overset{=}{o}$.

Comment: ahh thanks a lot @DMcMor

Comment: Also, what book is this?

Comment: this book is made by my professor, not an international known book

Comment: Ah.  In that case it's probably best to just ask your professor because it might not be standard notation.