# what is this little o double bar, is it big O notation?

Tags: calculus, notation, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

[image]

What is this little $\bar{\bar{o}}$?
My opinion is that this is the big $O$ notation.

But if it was the big O notation then why in the first line of the expansion they put $\overset{=}{o}(x^2)$ instead of $\overset{=}{o}(x^3)$, because the term that have $x^2$ is already before $\overset{=}{o}(x^2)$, right?

In case you didn't understand the image (because it's messed up) :

\begin{array}{l}
f(x)=\frac{\sqrt[n]{1+x}-1}{x}=\frac{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{x}=\frac{1+\frac{1}{n} \cdot x+\frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 \cdot\left(\frac{1}{n}-1\right) \cdot x^{2}+\overset{=}{o}\left(x^{2}\right)-1}{x} \\
=\frac{\frac{1}{n} x+\frac{1-n}{2 n^{2}} x^{2}+\overset{=}{o}\left(x^{2}\right)}{x}=\frac{x \cdot\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1-n}{2 . n^{2}} x+\overset{=}{o}(x)\right)}{x}=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1-n}{2 \cdot n^{2}} \cdot x+\overset{=}{o}(x) \\
\Rightarrow \quad \lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sqrt[n]{1+x}-1}{x}=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1-n}{2 \cdot n^{2}} \cdot x+\overset{=}{o}(x)\right)=\frac{1}{n}
\end{array}

Comment: I think it's the [little-o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) which is a variant of big-O. The source should define its notation....

Comment: i'll check it out

Comment: Please do not ask the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4281072/what-is-little-o-double-bar-is-it-like-big-o-notation) twice.